# UML Diagram for Locations of Components

Tags: uml, deployment, diagrams

I am about to deploy a new project that will have different components being deployed on different servers and in different web sites/technologies/etc. I was just wondering what would be the best way to communicate this with the business?

I want to show that Service X will exist on server Y as a Windows Service and Service Z will exist on server Q as a .NET web service etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Deployment diagram as the following.

[image]

Comment: Use package boundaries as well to highlight physical deployment issues: City 1/City 2, or 3rd floor/basement.